# Do transition to left between page in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, transition, snapchat

I would like to achieve IONIC application that allows a transition from right to left (and up to down, and others) between two pages, much like Snapchat. To switch from the main screen (the camera) in the center, to the list of snap on left and the list of stories on right.

Do you have an idea / solution to this problem?

PS: Snapchat is just one example, I do not wish to reproduce the application itself, but if you want me to examples in the basis for comparison, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use ion-slides for transition from right to left http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/

There should be other solutions for other type of transitions (for example https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-ion-tinder-cards) however mixing all type of transitions and in different directions might be confusing for the end user. I would suggest to stick with the standard UI controls and behavior which is clear and unambiguous for the end user.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. And if I want to do transition from up to down ?